# Good method for storing form data without submission in ASP.NET CORE

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

If I have a form on a page like so - (note the model property):

```
<form asp-action="ProcessQuote" id="form-calc-total">
    <p id="calc-item">@Model.TheCounter.Value</p>
    <button id="btn-add">+</button>
    <button id="btnContinue" onclick="document.getElementById('form-calc-total').submit();">CONTINUE</button>
</form>
```

Let's say I have an event listener on the form so when `btn-add` is clicked, it triggers the following JS function which adds 1 to the counter.

```
function calculatorClick() {
    let cou = document.querySelector('#calc-item');
    cou.innerHTML = Number(cnt) + 1;
}
```

So now when the form submits, it hits the controller and within that I can store the number (@Model.TheCounter.Value) in a session variable if I want:

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString(SESSION_GUID, model.TheCounter);
```

That means if I revisit the page I can pull out the session variable and populate that field again.

But that's only stored ***on form submission*** - How can I get a session variable to store after each button click so it'd remember the counter without someone having to submit the form first?

I vaguely remember in PHP that there were SESSION variables that could be added to directly on the page with JS (I think) - but how can I do this within an ASP.NET CORE framework / MVC pattern?

Is this something `AJAX` would be used for?

Comment: browsers localstorage will help in this case you can store alot of information.

Comment: Yes, you can use AJAX to send data to the server without a form submission.

Answer (score 1):

> But that's only stored on form submission - How can I get a session
> variable to store after each button click so it'd remember the counter
> without someone having to submit the form first?

The session value was stored on the server side, if you want to update and get the session value, you could create an Action method, then use JQuery Ajax to call this method and then update the session and get the latest value.

More detail information about using JQuery Ajax with Asp.net Core, see the following links:

[jQuery AJAX and JSON Example in ASP.Net Core MVC](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Core-jQuery-AJAX-and-JSON-Example-in-ASPNet-Core-MVC.aspx)

[How to use jQuery AJAX method to call an Action method in ASP.NET Core](https://www.yogihosting.com/jquery-ajax-aspnet-core/)

Besides, on the client side, you could also use web storage API to store the data, check the following tutorials:

[Using the Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API)

[HTML Web Storage API](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: Wow I had no idea about localStorage and sessionStorage - so damn easy to use!! Thanks for the links. I had started using the AJAX and COOKIES but actually this Web Storage has made this 10x easier.